# Limit rows while fetching records using QueryDatabase Table using NiFi

Tags: database, apache-nifi

I am trying to use QueryDatabase processor using Apache NiFi
Is there any way I can limit the records something like : “select * from table limit 100”

Any other processor in NiFi which supports this operation?

Answer (score 5):

Use **[ExecuteSQL](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/174341/how-can-i-use-variable-on-query-of-executesql-proc.html)** processor for this case.

- Configure/Enable DBCP connection pool
- In **`SQL select query`** property value keep your ***select query***

  `select * from table limit 100`
  [image]

Now processor runs the configured **sql select query** and outputs the results of the query as a flowfile in `AVRO` format

Comment: Thanks a lot Shu... it worked. I have a Question though I cannot see these many options in my ExecuteSql processor. I have 1.7.0 version, is it something new on 1.8.0?

Comment: @Apurw,Yes i'm using 1.8.0 `executesql` processor and there are lot of options added in latest version. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-1251